# How to access windows folder (that installed on virtualbox) via Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox

What is the solution that make me can access windows folder (windows installed on Virtualbox) via Linux

how to let me can access like this:

```
~$ cd /path/to/c:/Windows
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make sure that have install Guest Additions. From the Virtual Box's menu go to ***Devices*** → ***Install Guest Additions***.

With Guest Additions installed you may now go ahead and define the shared folder(s).

Comment: As far as i know, you can't designate guest directories as shared folder. You can only do that with host directories.

Comment: The "windows folder " is in name.vdi .  You cannot acces this folder from linux.  If you need something of this folder, start Vbox, and put what you want on a usb stick. (you must have installed guest additions).  Then via this guest addition unmount you USB in Vbox - and go back to Linux.  There you can reach the USB.